# Actual bytes read and written by IO::Socket::SSL

Tags: perl, ssl

I'd like to count bytes in/out from a socket. For a regular socket, I can just total the size change of buffer effected by recv() and the return value of send(). How do you do this with IO::Socket::SSL?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you want to measure throughput, you want to count the unencrypted data. If you want to measure the amount of data sent over your connection, then your approach doesn't even work for non-encrypted connections (because it doesn't include the packet headers and resent packets).

Comment: The latter. Yes, I'm aware of the packet headers and resent packets issue; I'm willing to accept an approximate value based on bytes counted from send() and recv().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IO::Socket::SSL does not provide you with that view to the underlying TCP socket since it let just OpenSSL handle the TCP socket (via Net::SSLeay). In order to get such details you would need to handle read/write on the TCP socket yourself and then interact with the SSL layer using the BIO interface. Of course, this is way more complex than just using the abstraction offered by IO::Socket::SSL.